# Postgres docker container init scripts not running when extending another image tag

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have dockerfile which has the following command for building the image

```
FROM postgres:9.6.2-alpine

COPY postgresql.conf /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgresql.conf
COPY postgres-*.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

CMD ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/docker-entrypoint- 
initdb.d/postgresql.conf"]
```

and from this image in the repository I am creating another local docker image as

```
ARG FROM_IMAGE_TAG=v9.6.2-latest
FROM <url for the image above>:${FROM_IMAGE_TAG}
COPY postgres-create-zfunction.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The script in the 2nd dockerfile is copied to the container but it is not getting executed. When I tried to run the scipt locally it is working perfect inside the container, however during start up it is not getting executed and I do not see any logs for errors in the container too.

Any suggestions on how to run the script will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing the volume mapping which was created when I first ran the docker-compose build. So every-time I want to run the scripts I have to delete the volume mapping in local filesystem and do the docker-compose up or build commands

see the comment by  blag on this issue https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/40